# What do we do if we want a subjective answer?

Tags: discussion

Not sure what to say here, but if we have a question that says "this may be closed because it is subjective" or whatever, then where do I post the subjective question?

Comment: If you got this warning when posting either of the questions you've currently asked, don't worry too much - neither of your questions is too subjective for Arqade, but the language you used may have tripped up the algorithm and given it the wrong impression. Fortunately, moderation is done by humans, not machines! (Well, except for @ashleynunn) so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I am only part machine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Let me explain something, StackExchange is not a discussion platform like forums, it is more about solid questions and answers that can be proved (and are not subjective), so you don't have much chance to get an answer in StackExchange's main websites (as in everywhere that isn't chat).

But guess what, I have two solutions for you.

**One: Chatroom**

Try our [Chatroom called The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) once you get enough rep ([20](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)), the chatroom might not be that helpful though, as it has a different theme (as in the way of communication) than the website. I'd recommend introducing yourself, determining the people that played the game (or if you are looking for game recommendations, look out for people that liked the games you liked) and asking them your question.

Just a warning: THE CHATROOMS ARE INDEXED BY SEARCH ENGINES AND YOU CAN'T EDIT/REMOVE YOUR MESSAGES AFTER TWO MINUTES.

**Two: Other Websites**

Try the game's official forums if it has one (every game on Steam has one on Steam), or try other websites (reddit etc, try the game's subreddit if it has one).

If your question is a game recommendation question, I'd recommend /r/gamingsuggestions.

Comment: Not all subjective questions are bad. Please read: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/